# How to cast a ray and detect intersecting points on a 3D object with Python?

Tags: javascript, python, 3d, geometry, raycasting

I have an array of 3D coordinates that make up a 3D object (a sphere in this example)

[image]

I want to cast a ray from the origin along a vector and calculate any points at which the ray intersects with the 3D object.

In this diagram I want to find point 1 and point 2.

I am using Python, so I would prefer an approach that I can use Python with.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Find what point is the closest to the ray using [line-point distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line).

Find mesh cells around that point and calculate [line-triangle intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ller%E2%80%93Trumbore_intersection_algorithm) to get intersection point(s).

---

If you have sphere equation (center and radius) - it is simpler to calculate [exact intersections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93sphere_intersection)