# How to get texture coordinate from ray cast hit?

Tags: kotlin, libgdx, raycasting, bullet

I'm using LibGDX and Bullet to create a screen for my Android app for painting on a textured 3D models.
I'm trying to get the coordinate on the texture from the ray hit on the 3D model. But I'm completely clueless how to do this, there's no documentation regarding this, ChatGPT didn't helped also))

I'm already able to display the 3D model (g3db) with its texture (png) and perform the raycast on it. But how I can now find out what the coordinate on texture the user pointed to with raycast?

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched) {
            callback.closestHitFraction = 1f
            callback.collisionObject = null

            val ray = cam.getPickRay(Gdx.input.x.toFloat(), Gdx.input.y.toFloat())
            rayFromWorld.set(ray.origin)
            rayToWorld.set(ray.direction).scl(5f).add(ray.origin)

            bulletPhysicsSystem?.raycast(rayFromWorld, rayToWorld, callback)

            if (callback.hasHit()) {
                val collisionObject = callback.collisionObject
                if (collisionObject is btRigidBody) {
                    println("Hit detected!")
                }
            }
}
```

### Update

I've thrown away the Bullet usage for this task.
Now I'm trying to use the barycentric coordinates of the intersection point to find out the UV coordinates and finally convert them to the texture coordinates.

**The flow I came up with:**

1. Obtaining all triangles from the model
2. Finding the ray cast hit intersection triangle and point
3. Conversion of the intersection point and triangle to barycentric coordinates
4. Conversion of barycentric coordinates to UV values
5. Conversion of UV values to the actual texture coordinates.
6. Attempt to draw on the obtained texture coordinates to see if it works.

I'm able to obtain sometimes the right coordinates but it's completely unreliable, drawing on the front face completely brings drawing points to the back face, and in general even on other faces the texture coordinates I'm getting are wrong somehow depending on the model rotation. [video](https://youtube.com/shorts/UNhqj1kb1rk?feature=share)

I'm completely out of any variants of what is going wrong here

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched) {

            val ray = cam.getPickRay(Gdx.input.x.toFloat(), Gdx.input.y.toFloat())

            val meshPart = instance!!.model.meshParts[0]

            val numVertices = meshPart.mesh.numVertices
            val vertexSize = meshPart.mesh.vertexSize / 4
            val vertices = FloatArray(numVertices * vertexSize)
            meshPart.mesh.getVertices(0, vertices.size, vertices)

            val indices = ShortArray(meshPart.mesh.numIndices)
            meshPart.mesh.getIndices(indices)

            println("Vertices: ${vertices.asList()}")
            println("Vertex size: $vertexSize")
            println("Num vertices: $numVertices")
            println("Indices: ${indices.asList()}")

            val triangles = mutableListOf<ModelTriangle>()
            for (i in indices.indices step 3) {
                val stride = meshPart.mesh.vertexSize / 4
                val vertexIndex1 = indices[i].toInt() * stride
                val vertexIndex2 = indices[i + 1].toInt() * stride
                val vertexIndex3 = indices[i + 2].toInt() * stride

                val vertex1 = Vector3(
                    vertices[vertexIndex1],
                    vertices[vertexIndex1 + 1],
                    vertices[vertexIndex1 + 2]
                )
                val vertex2 = Vector3(
                    vertices[vertexIndex2],
                    vertices[vertexIndex2 + 1],
                    vertices[vertexIndex2 + 2]
                )
                val vertex3 = Vector3(
                    vertices[vertexIndex3],
                    vertices[vertexIndex3 + 1],
                    vertices[vertexIndex3 + 2]
                )

                val vertexAttributes = meshPart.mesh.vertexAttributes
                val uvOffset =
                    vertexAttributes.findByUsage(VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates).offset / 4

                val uv1 = Vector2(
                    vertices[vertexIndex1 + uvOffset],
                    vertices[vertexIndex1 + uvOffset + 1]
                )
                val uv2 = Vector2(
                    vertices[vertexIndex2 + uvOffset],
                    vertices[vertexIndex2 + uvOffset + 1]
                )
                val uv3 = Vector2(
                    vertices[vertexIndex3 + uvOffset],
                    vertices[vertexIndex3 + uvOffset + 1]
                )

                val uvs = arrayOf(uv1, uv2, uv3)

                val triangle = ModelTriangle(vertex1, vertex2, vertex3, uvs)
                triangles.add(triangle)
            }

            println("Triangles: $triangles")
            println("Triangles size: ${triangles.size}")

            val intersectionPoint = Vector3()
            val intersectionTriangle = triangles.find {
                Intersector.intersectRayTriangle(
                    ray,
                    it.v1,
                    it.v2,
                    it.v3,
                    intersectionPoint
                )
            }

            println("Intersection point: $intersectionPoint")
            println("Is intersection found: ${intersectionTriangle != null}")

            intersectionTriangle?.let { triangle ->
                val instanceTexture =
                    instance!!.materials.first().get(TextureAttribute.Diffuse) as TextureAttribute
                val uv = getIntersectionUV(intersectionPoint, triangle, triangle.uvs)
                val textureX = (uv.x * instanceTexture.textureDescription.texture.width).toInt()
                val textureY = (uv.y * instanceTexture.textureDescription.texture.height).toInt()

                println("Texture coordinates: x: $textureX, y: $textureY")

                val texturePixmap = textureToPixmap(instanceTexture.textureDescription.texture)
                drawPointOnPixmap(texturePixmap, textureX, textureY, Color.RED)
                val newTexture = Texture(texturePixmap)
                instance!!.materials.first().set(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(newTexture))
            }

        }
```

*ModelTriangle* class:

```
data class ModelTriangle(
    val v1: Vector3,
    val v2: Vector3,
    val v3: Vector3,
    val uvs: Array<Vector2>
) {
    // equals and hashCode implementations automatically generated by AndroidStudio
}
```

*getIntersectionUV*:

```
    private fun getIntersectionUV(
        intersectionPoint: Vector3,
        triangle: ModelTriangle,
        uvs: Array<Vector2>
    ): Vector2 {
        val barycentricCoords = toBarycoord3D(
            intersectionPoint, triangle.v1, triangle.v2, triangle.v3
        )

        val isInsideTheTriangle = GeometryUtils.barycoordInsideTriangle(Vector2(barycentricCoords.x, barycentricCoords.y))
        println("Is inside the triangle: $isInsideTheTriangle")

        val uv1 = uvs[0]
        val uv2 = uvs[1]
        val uv3 = uvs[2]

        return Vector2(
            barycentricCoords.z * uv1.x + barycentricCoords.x * uv2.x + barycentricCoords.y * uv3.x,
            barycentricCoords.z * uv1.y + barycentricCoords.x * uv2.y + barycentricCoords.y * uv3.y
        )
    }
```

*toBarycoord3D*:

```
private fun toBarycoord3D(
        point: Vector3,
        a: Vector3,
        b: Vector3,
        c: Vector3,
    ): Vector3 {
        val v0 = Vector3().set(b).sub(a)
        val v1 = Vector3().set(c).sub(a)
        val v2 = Vector3().set(point).sub(a)

        val d00 = v0.dot(v0)
        val d01 = v0.dot(v1)
        val d11 = v1.dot(v1)
        val d20 = v2.dot(v0)
        val d21 = v2.dot(v1)

        val denom = d00 * d11 - d01 * d01
        val barycentricOut = Vector3()
        barycentricOut.x = (d11 * d20 - d01 * d21) / denom
        barycentricOut.y = (d00 * d21 - d01 * d20) / denom
        barycentricOut.z = 1.0f - barycentricOut.x - barycentricOut.y

        return barycentricOut
    }
```

[Full code](https://pastebin.com/HDK3F5GA)
[Assets I'm using](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zilT9cpxLEIVAaXQ0TzFLjllf0Lcma4Z?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm sure you want something pre-supplied but in the case that isn't available, this sums it up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61886655/how-to-cast-a-ray-and-detect-intersecting-points-on-a-3d-object-with-python

Comment: @londonBadger hi! Thanks for the link! I'm now trying to use the barycentric coordinates to solve the problem, but still no good results here. I would be very glad if you could briefly look through the code and maybe point me to what can be wrong here

Comment: Maybe try skipping testing triangles with the normal not facing the camera i.e. exclude the back, as they are valid intersections otherwise(but leave in at least something coming). Also if you are using a viewport you need to use pickray with the viewport not the camera. The intersections on the first 6 clicks although they appear on the back surface look correct but rotated 90 degrees up, while the ones on the top (green surface) look correct. Try with a test click pattern with an easy to see orientation.

Comment: I wonder because the top one works ok whether or not its something to with triangles having to be defined anti-clockwise with respect to the direction they are facing, which might be ruining the calculation where to draw on the texture i.e. the interect detection is correct but the red square position is outside the triangle. You could count how many red squares are drawn vs how many appear.

Comment: @londonBadger https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/6882 - here was the part of the problem. Also, I've created my custom model in Blender to understand what is going on there entirely. The problem is that ray passes through all of the triangles on its way and I get all of them instead of the one which was hit first.

Comment: Fixed the problem by finding the closest triangle to the camera position. Will post the full answer later as well as a fully functional refactored solution to GitHub.